# C# - easy to use graphic library

Tags: c#, drawing, 2d

Good day everyone.

I have a question regarding drawing libraries for C#. I always use XNA because it's really easy to use and is very convenient in all aspects, but...

For new project one of requirements is that it is not needed to install additional libraries or other stuff on a client's pc. So I can't use XNA :(

Can you suggest me some REALLY easy to use 2d library? I don't need 3d. Basically I need only 2d premitives and sprite rendering.

I looked in DX and GL direction but it is complete overkill... and to tell you the truth I have no idea how to use neither of it... nor I'm particularly happy to learn it :)

So anyway, what easy 2d drawing library can you suggest me to use? It'd be good if this library specifically written for C# and include detailed tutorials / documentation.

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this was asked before.

Comment: And you can't get away with static linking or ILMerge?

Comment: errr, I'm sorry I have no idea whar you are saying :)

Comment: Static linking allows you to compile a library directly into the binary. ILMerge creates a bundled .exe with the library included in it. Neither one would require you to install the library on the client computer.

Comment: Oh, can you give me a link to some info about it? It sounds perfect if I really can do it.

Comment: @Chris: I've never worked with XNA, but are you sure ILMerge would merge everything needed? My blind guess is that XNA runtime is not a single (several) dll-s. I thought of it as a full-fledged framework... Maybe I was wrong. Also, are you sure that XNA licence allows that?

Comment: @Kornelije: your guess is as good as mine. ILMerge can merge *many* assemblies, as long as they are ALL .NET. Otherwise probably not. As for licensing? I am not a lawyer.

Comment: There are pixel map supporting controls for both WPF and Window Forms.  Those are built into the .Net framework.  You could try using one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you could try one of two strategies:

- Static linking
- ILMerge

Static linking is a bit of a misnomer in C#. I guess the better phrase would be "compiled-in". If you have the source code for the library, just include it directly in your project rather than referencing the external library.

ILMerge is a utility by Microsoft (found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)) which can take multiple .NET assemblies and merge them into one (i.e. pack the exe and library into a combined exe). There is some [very good documentation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx) on ILMerge.

Comment: I googled that and it seems that it is possible. Thank you :)